# virtualized filer configuration for Win 2008r2 for 7 TB of data

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, storage-area-network

I'm using Hyper-V on 2008 R2 and I have to serve about 7 TB of network shares through SMB. The underlying storage is a SAN. I planned two configurations:

1. self contained Windows 2008R2 guest of 7TB. But .vhd files can only be 2TB in size. So, I should attach multiple .vhd files to the VM and merge those at the OS level.
2. Put the 7TB of data on a iSCSI volume, and access it from a small Windows 2008R2 VM that serve the data over SMB.

I would prefer the semplicity of the first solution, but I'm not sure about the resiliency. What do you think?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the actual SAN make/model?

Comment: It's a Dell SCV2020

Comment: Ok so it's got FC and iSCSI, well in that case I'd go with option 2, I've seen setups like option 1 work for a while but they always seem 'fragile' to me and set my OCD off a bit :)

Comment: Why not option 3? Upgrade to Windows Server 2012 R2 and use a VHDX, which maxes out at 64TB.

Comment: I guess second option will be fine. Also, I agree with @joeqwerty, you should upgrade to 2012 or 2016 and just use .vhdx

Comment: thanks a lot for the hints. I'm planning to migrate to 2012 actually, in the meantime I think I'll go with #2